# throw an exception from org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.RequestHandler handleRequest method

Tags: cxf

I have this problem using cxf dispatching behavior.
I have developed an Interceptor that implements the org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.RequestHandler interface.
In its "public Response handleRequest(Message m, ClassResourceInfo resourceClass)" method I throw an exception (e.g. a WebServiceException) or a Fault. I have not apparent problems but, on the client side, the client receives a different exception (a ServerWebApplicationException) with the error message empty.

Here the code:

Server side:

```
    public class RestInterceptor implements RequestHandler {
       ......
       @Override
       public Response handleRequest(Message m, ClassResourceInfo resourceClass){
          .....
          throw new WebServiceException("Failure in the dispatching ws invocation!");
          .....
       }
    }
```

ServerWebApplicationException received on client side:

```
Status : 500
Headers : 
Content-Length : 0
Connection : close
Server : Jetty(7.x.y-SNAPSHOT)

cause=null
detailMessage=null
errorMessage=""
.....
```

I received the same exception also if I throw a Fault.
What is the problem? I have to use another exception? Why?
Thanks a lot,

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution.
I've registered an ExceptionMapper on the dispatcher and use it to encapsulate the exception inside the Response sent to the client.
To do this the interceptor is registered as provider at the web service publication and it implements the "ExceptionMapper" interface. In its "toResponse" method it encapsulates the exception in the Response.
Look at code:

```
    public static<T extends Throwable>  Response convertFaultToResponse(T ex, Message inMessage) {
        ExceptionMapper<T>  mapper = ProviderFactory.getInstance(inMessage).createExceptionMapper(ex.getClass(), inMessage);
        if (mapper != null) {
            try {
                return mapper.toResponse(ex);
            } catch (Exception mapperEx) {
                mapperEx.printStackTrace();
                return Response.serverError().build();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception arg0) {
        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).type("application/xml");
        String message = arg0.toString();
        return builder.entity(message).build(); 
    }
```

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your exception with [@WebFault](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/WebFault.html)

example :

```
@WebFault(name = "oauthFault")
public class OAuthException extends RuntimeException {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately I've tried but continues with the same wrong behavior and the same empty ServerWebApplicationException is received on the client side.